# Replace deprecated jQuery "live" to "on" format using RegEx?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, visual-studio

I updated jQuery in an application with 1000+ screens and would like to do a mass update from "live" to "on" for the event handlers.

I plan on bubbling everything to the document just to make the application run at least. That will give me enough time to take another pass on it manually and update from document to some parent element.

I'm trying to replace this format:

```
$("#some-id").live('click', function () //or
$('.some-class').live('submit', function ()
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', "#some-id", function () //or
$(document).on('submit', '.some-class', function ()
```

I'm using Visual Studio but can use another software if needed to do the mass search/replace. Anyone know of a RegEx to do this, even if it takes a couple of expressions to do this?

Comment: I'm no expert with regex but I doubt you'll find one which replaces $("#id").live('click' with $(document).on('click', '#id'

Comment: @artm, not even considering things like `var elems = matchSomething(); elems.live(...);`

Comment: It's a solid pattern, doesn't seem too crazy for RegEx. Why the downvote from someone tho, migrating legacy apps is common.

Comment: I've add more background and examples to the question. Upvote back pls :)

Comment: @TruMan1, for what it's worth, the last line of your second code snippet is not a valid use of `on()`.

Comment: Thx I've added `.selector` and should work I hope.

Comment: @TruMan1, not really, `selector` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9.

Comment: I appreciate it @FrédéricHamidi, I've removed the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, with the string selectors, you'd want to

find `\$\(\s*(["'][^"']*['"])\s*\)\.live\(([^,]*)`

and replace with `$(document).on(\2, \1`

(I haven't used visual studio in a while, so I don't know if it does regex, or if it uses `\2` or `$2` for substitution).

For the second case, with a variable, you'd want:

find `([^\s"()']+)\.live\(([^,]*)`

Note this one is more risky because any call to a `.live` method on an object will end up changed.  Probably OK if you don't have any functions called `live`.

In either case I'd probably do each replacement one at a time to make sure it's doing the right thing.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 uses $1, $2, etc. to reference groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that's pretty close.  It doesn't strip off the jquery selectors like you asked for the second parameter of the output.

```
var output = input.replace(/(\S.*)[.]live[(]([^,]+),/g, "$$(document).on($2, $1,");
```

This regex is in javascript, as specified in your question tags, but it should be able to translate to any language.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qc2homx6/